# String cut in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle, substring

I need to use SQL to extract only the `YES` or `NO` from the below strings:

```
'5^hgf^A^6^YES@1^g'
'H^jfd^k^i^NO@2^ojg'
```

So far I tried this regex:

```
Regexp(column_name,[^^|],1,4)
```

We need characters between `@` and `^`, specifically `YES` and `NO`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you working on a specific database? That might be relevant to the regex parser used by the database. Add it as a tag if so.

Comment: We are working on Oracle database.

Comment: As an alternative, perhaps use a case expression such as `case when col_name like '%YES@%' then 'YES' else 'NO' end`

Comment: I don't see a `REGEXP()` function in the Oracle manual; I think the function you're looking for is [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099) And the regexp should be in quotes, not square brackets.

Comment: Rather than, “We need characters between @ and ^, specifically YES and NO” it sounds like your objective is to extract the string `”YES”` or `”NO”` provide it is preceded by `”^”` and followed by ‘“@“`”.

Comment: It looks like the 5th field when delimited by '^''s can be further delimited by '@''s.  If this is true is the value you are after always the first one? Could there ever be any additional values after the number?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, as you may have noticed by now. So, there are substrings between `^` and `@`. How many of these can occur in one string? Only one as in your examples or more? Then you mention that you are "specifically" in YES and NO. What does this mean? That they just happen to be the most common, but there are other values that are less common which you are also interested in? Or are you really just interested in YES and NO only? What if none of these is in the string?

Answer (score 1):

If real data really looks like sample data you posted, then it is the 5th "word" you're looking for. In that case, this might do:

```
with test (col) as 
  (select '5^hgf^A^6^YES@1^g' from dual union all
   select 'H^jfd^k^i^NO@2^ojg' from dual
  )
select col,
  regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 5) result_1,
  substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 4) + 1,
              instr(col, '@') - instr(col, '^', 1, 4) - 1
        ) result_2
from test;
```

- `result_1` uses regular expression and looks prettier
- `result_2` uses `substr + instr` combination, extracting string between 4th `^` character and `@`

Have a look at the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6QnmBIqL).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to compare length of string with length of string where YES/NO are removed if present...

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS  --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
        (   Select '5^hgf^A^6^YES@1^g' "TXT" From Dual Union All
            Select 'H^jfd^k^i^NO@2^ojg'  "TXT" From Dual Union All
            Select '5^hgf^A^6^YES@1^g^NO@' "TXT" From Dual Union All
            Select 'H^jfd^k^i^XX@2^ojg'  "TXT" From Dual
        )
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select  TXT, Case When Length(TXT) > Length(Replace(TXT, '^YES@')) And Length(TXT) > Length(Replace(TXT, '^NO@')) Then 'YES_NO'
                  When Length(TXT) > Length(Replace(TXT, '^YES@')) Then 'YES'
                  When Length(TXT) > Length(Replace(TXT, '^NO@')) Then 'NO'
             Else 'None'
             End "FLAG"
From    tbl
/*    R e s u l t :
TXT                   FLAG  
--------------------- ------
5^hgf^A^6^YES@1^g     YES   
H^jfd^k^i^NO@2^ojg    NO    
5^hgf^A^6^YES@1^g^NO@ YES_NO
H^jfd^k^i^XX@2^ojg    None     */
```

Comment: why not just use INSTR instead ? Same logic, less code or am I missing something ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie You are not missing anything, this is just one of the options that are faster than regexp. Put it cause of the title - string cut...

Answer (score 0):

THis is the most optimum answer to your question:

```
select output from (Select Rownum r, 'YES'  as output
From dual
Connect By Rownum <=(SELECT REGEXP_COUNT ('5^hYESgf^A^6^YES@1^g''H^jfd^k^i^NO@2^ojg', 'YES')
FROM dual) 
union
Select Rownum r, 'NO'  as output
From dual
Connect By Rownum <=(SELECT REGEXP_COUNT ('5^hYESgf^A^6^YES@1^g''H^jfd^k^i^NO@2^ojg', 'NO')
FROM dual))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *capture pattern*.

```
(?:.+?\^){4}([^@]+)
```